# SignalR self hosting generates target invocation error

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

[image: Console application]
[image: Html page where server function is being called]
[image: App configuration file]
[image: output before error]

I am facing some problem in running signalR on TCP protocol. If I change url to `http://localhost:8080` then it works fine but when I am trying to run it on `net.tcp://localhost:8040` it gives me target invocation error. Any help will be appreciated :) Version of signalR is 1.1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR is built on HTTP you can't use it with TCP directly.